# Padding the colored background of a span of text?

Tags: html, css

I have a long paragraph (inline element) of white text, that can span several lines, on a black background - not the background of the whole box, but of the of the text itself. I do this by putting the text in a <span> element with specifications of color and backround-color.

I want to make some horizontal space between the edge of the black background of the text and the letters. When I add padding to the span, left and right padding appear only before and after the first and last characters of the whole <span>, but not in the beginning of each line, and I want each line to start and end with some space to the edge of the black background.

The text is continuous and changing (and the letters are not fixed-space) so I can't artificially add &nbsp; elements to the beginning and end of each line, which is the only way I have been able to find so far to create that space.

Is it really impossible to make space at the beginning and end of each line an inline flowing piece of text?

Answer (score 1):

Not on a `span` tag, use a `p` tag or put it into a `div`.

Paddings and margins can't be applied to spans

Answer (score 0):

As C. Malet said, its not possible with `span` coz its inline.. 
if you use `div` or `p` or css property "display:block", then background will be applied as whole but not for each lines..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I found a way to do this by nesting the span inside two additional spans with offsets to the right and to the left:

```
.theSpan { position: relative; right: 5px; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; } 
.outer1 { position: relative; background-color: #000000; }
.outer2 { position: relative; left: 10px; background-color: #000000; }
```